# On iPhone, tap outside span to fade it out

Tags: jquery, iphone, tooltip

I have the following jQuery code,

```
 setTips: function() {
            $(".tooltip").parent().hover(function(){
            //store the tooltip being hovered
            TT.current = $(this);
            TT.timer = setTimeout(function(){
                //find the tooltip
                TT.current.find(".tooltip").fadeIn('fast');
                }, TT.delay);
            }, function(){
                //on mouseout, clear timer and hide tooltip
                clearTimeout(TT.timer);
                $(this).find(".tooltip").fadeOut('fast');
```

Which works well on an browser, however on the iphone, whenever the tooltip appears, there's no way to hide it.

Is there a way to tap outside of the span and have it fade out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a generic click event that hides tooltips on any tap, such as this?

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).hasClass('.element-that-called-tooltip') ) return; // return if the tapped element was one that called the tooltip
    $('.tooltip').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

EDIT:

So the problem was with iOS hover events. I'd say the best way to mitigate this is to use feature detection (with a library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)), and bind hover events for non-touch devices, and click events for touch devices.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RAJ5Q/1/

```
if ( $('html').hasClass('no-touch') ) {
    // bind to hover
}
else {
    // bind to click
}
```

Comment: That worked well to hide the tooltip, however, if I try to click on the element that brings the tooltip back, it no longer does. It stays hidden.

Comment: Did you modify the first line of the function (specifically the class selector) to return if the clicked element is one that triggers a tooltip?

Comment: No I did not, I just included the code you gave me, which works perfectly on a browser actually. After clicking on the tag, it fades out and when mousing back over, the tooltip fades back in. However on the iPhone, it doesn't come back after closing it.

Comment: Hmm, hard to say what's happening. It could be kind of tricky to solve though, iOS' implementation of 'hover-taps' can actually cause problems when javascript is involved. Perhaps if you made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) we could play with it?

Comment: The issue is as I suspected, iOS doesn't want to register the 'hover-tap' event because it thinks the element is still in focus. Try tapping on another section of the editor, then go back to the result and tap on the text and it comes back again. You'd be better off detecting the type of device, and then setting the tooltip based on that. I'll give you a demo in a tic.

Comment: I've edited my answer and updated the jsFiddle with an example that seems to work on desktop and mobile. Check it out and let me know how it works :)